# Why is LinkedIn not fetching correct og tags from my URL

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, linkedin-jsapi, share-open-graph

I am trying to use OG tags to share my links on social media. However, for some reasons, LinkedIn is not capturing correct tags from my link. When I share on LinkedIn, it seems to pick the default favicon and not the image from the tags.

Facebook, Whatsapp, MS Teams seem to capture everything correctly. Also, I have checked on the official OG inspector and it shows/reads correct tags.

Is there anything extra that needs to be done for LinkedIn? Can someone please help here?

My example link: https://api.oguild.com/interactionms/shareable/BusinessModelInnovation-YtMEj7-qkw_an_mpFbGJUy7RqEU

OG Inspector data: https://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.oguild.com%2Finteractionms%2Fshareable%2FBusinessModelInnovation-YtMEj7-qkw_an_mpFbGJUy7RqEU#.YUwwqI4zY2w

I have read the official docs [here](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en) and I am sending the data in the same format.